# Generic onclick event binded to item, not activity or fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

I have a context menu button nested in a row layout (xml) which opens a popup to display context menu options. I use this row for several listViews in different Fragments, but the context menu items should always behave the same (update something in the database).

I was wondering if it is possible to write the onClick event handler for the row and not for every activity/fragment.

I guess I don't see the wood for the trees, but I couldn't think of a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

add this in your button's layout(xml)

```
android:onClick="yourmethod"
```

and create the method in your activity like:

```
public void yourmethod(View v) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But using this I still have to implement this method for every activity that uses the row. I'd like to have class, e.g. "MyRowContextClick" which holds the onclick event for the button :)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to make it happen

Comment: What about extending the popup dialog class and overriding the onClick event? Didn't try, but do you think that could work?